# Programmatically create nested array

Tags: arrays, go, multidimensional-array, nested

I want to test my serialization format for robustnes and want to serialize a nested array. The Serialization actually dies at some point, but I don't know at what depth exactly. Right now I just define a large array manually, but I want to do it programmatically, so I can figure out when exactly the depth is too high. Changing the code for each iteration is tedious...

```
l := [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]string {{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{{"a"}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
l := "a"
while(1){
    l = {l} //nest the slice/array once more
    print("round ", i)
    i++
}
```

I'm a Golang newbie and I don't know how I can get around the type-safety in this case.

Comment: You cannot really do what you want unless you want to use interface{}.

Comment: @Volker Can I somehow make that array from the interface? Can you please elaborate on that point a bit more? I was thinking this should somehow work via reflection, right? Making a new object from the nested one?

Comment: You can put anything into an interface{} even a slice like []interface{} so no need to reflect here. What is unclear here?

Comment: @Volker As I said, I'm a Golang newbie so the whole concept of an interface and how I would use it was not clear to me. But luckily Nordiii provided a good example and actual feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In go you can't change the type of a variable so you need to use interface{} as type `var l interface{}` now you could do something like:

```
l = "a"
for i:= 0;i<3;i++{
    l = []interface{}{l}
}
```

printing l would give the output `[[[a]]]`, same as `[][][]string{{{"a"}}}`.

A problem is that you lose your type and it will be impossible to do something like `l[0][0][0]` to get the value. As far as I now you would need to cast everything `l.([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(string)`

Comment: s/cast/type assert/g